# When I boot Ubuntu using the bootloader Windows Boot Manager error appears

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

When I boot Ubuntu using the bootloader, it shows an error about not being able to load Windows.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance.
```

When I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, Ubuntu loads perfectly. Is there a way to stop this message popping up every time I boot Ubuntu. Windows 7 boots fine when I choose to boot it.

Comment: Is this a BIOS or an UEFI system?  could you try boot-repair?